# Problemas para descompactar arquivos em RAR no Linux UBUNTU

Tags: linux

boa tarde!

Tenho um servidor que roda em um servidor Cloud Web LINUX UBUNTU SERVER, há 7 anos, migrei para outro servidor local também com LINUX UBUNTU SERVER.

No linux da Cloud o APACHE com PHP E MySQL rodava em /var/www, os arquivos criados pelas rotinas de UPLOAD, eram de propriedade do usuário WWW-DATA. O SHELL_EXEC, comando que utilizo no PHP para executar linhas de comando do S.O. e para descompactar arquivos através da função UNRAR, funcionava perfeitamente.

Porém, neste servidor novo, o usuário ROOT em tese "Não existe" o usuário padrão é "usuario@life" que foi o usuário informado na instalação do servidor, sempre que preciso de algo como administrador executo o comando SUDO anteriormente, e coloco a senha deste usuário que em tese é o ROOT. Mas não tem como dar SUDO e passar uma senha através do SHELL_EXEC, pelo menos desconheço como fazer isso.

O problema é que os UPLOAD feitos ficam em propriedade de um usuário chamado DAEMON, os arquivos ficam dentro de /opt/lampp/htdocs/ conseguimos trocar para sempre fazer UPLOAD como WWW-DATA, porém a propriedade do arquivo de upload é de "usuario@life" com permissão de criar pasta e escrita, a pasta é criada mas o arquivo não consegue ser descompactado dentro dela, já rodamos o comando na linha de comando e funciona normalmente.

Vocês tem alguma ideia do que possa ser? O usuário DAEMON já está no grupo de administradores, o www-data também, assim como o root que criei e o usuario@life, mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: A principio pra descompactar um arquivo o usuário precisa de permissão de leitura nele e de escrita no destino. Você ja tentou descompactar para outro lugar, como por exemplo o /tmp: `unrar e arquivo.rar /tmp/`? Isso ajuda a identificar a permissao que falta. Vc disse que todos esses usuários estão no mesmo grupo, mas qual o GID dos arquivos .rar e do diretorio onde serão descompactados? Se for tudo do mesmo grupo desses usuarios, o grupo tem as permissoes de leitura e escrita adequadas?